# all data is in page 1 after calling tbody via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

May I ask for assistance regarding this matter? I checked every guide regarding this concern, and followed all guide, but no luck.

When the table is populated via AJAX call, all the data is in a single page only.

I tried adding the whole dataTable script into the tbody caller, but no luck.

These are the following codes.

This is my `<?php include 'ajax-process/earnings_amendment_account-ajax-table.php'; ?>`

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {                  
                $.ajax({
                url:'table_body/earnings_amendment_account_table_body.php',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
                success:json,

               });

               function json(data){
                   $("#earnings_amendment_account_body").empty();
                   $(data).each(function(index,value)  {
                        console.log(value);
                        var table = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + value.accountcode + '</td>'+
                        '<td>' + value.accounttitle + '</td>'+
                        '<td>' + value.accounttype + '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                        $('#earnings_amendment_account').append( table );});
                        }
                        }, 1000);
                        $('#earnings_amendment_account').dataTable();

            });
</script>
```

This is my table in *`index.php`*

```
<table id="earnings_amendment_account" class="table table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed; display: none">
                <thead>

                  <th>Account Code</th>
                  <th>Account Title</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>

                </thead>
                <tbody id="earnings_amendment_account_body">

                </tbody>
              </table>
```

This is my *`table_body/earnings_amendment_account_table_body.php`*

```
<?php
include '../backend/conn.php';
include '../backend/session.php';
$params=array();
$sql = "SELECT accountcode,accounttype,accounttitle,accounttype,postedby,dateposted,
approvedby,dateapproved FROM earningsamendmentaccount";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
if ($query === false ) { echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit; }                  
$dbdata = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$dbdata[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
                  ?>
```

This is my dataTable.

> // all of the function in this dataTable is still not included because I'm testing if everything works well when my dataTable body is being called via AJAX.

```
<script>
function format ( dataSource ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" class="table table-bordered">';
    for (var key in dataSource){
        html += '<tr>'+
                   '<td>' + key             +'</td>'+
                   '<td>' + dataSource[key] +'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    } return html += '</table>';  }
var earnings_amendment_account_table = $('#earnings_amendment_account').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    });
      $('#earnings_amendment_account').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = earnings_amendment_account_table.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format({
                  'Posted By : ' : tr.data('key-1'),
                  'Date Posted : ' : tr.data('key-2'),
                  'Approved By : ' :  tr.data('key-3'),
                  'Date Approved : ' :  tr.data('key-4')
              })).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          } });
</script>
```

The data is being passed on console. **Showing 0 out of 0 Entries**, but the data is on display in the page.

Top:
[image]

Bottom:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is i did basic example of datatabe, you need to follow this things if you are using datatable and do custom thing.

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html leng="en">
<head>
    <title>Display Emloyee </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="tabl_user">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>F Name</th>
                        <th>L Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#tabl_user').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150],
                "columnDefs" : [{orderable:false, targets:[1] }],
                "ajax": "trylimited.php"
            } );
        });
        </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

trylimited.php

```
<?php
include "con.php"; 
$column = array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_no', 'mobile','city', 'zip');
$sIndexColumn = "id";
$sTable = "elision_user";
// Searching 
$wherecondition = "";

if($_REQUEST['search']['value'] != "")
{

    $wherecondition = "WHERE (";
    for($i=0; $i<count($column); $i++)
    {
        $wherecondition .="".$column[$i]." LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['search']['value']."%' OR ";

    }       
    $wherecondition = substr_replace($wherecondition, "", -3);
    $wherecondition .=')';

}
$draw = $_REQUEST['draw'];
$start = $_REQUEST['start'];
$limit = $_REQUEST['length'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM allinone";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM elision_user";
$sql1.=" $wherecondition ORDER BY ".$column[$_REQUEST['order'][0]['column']]." ".$_REQUEST['order'][0]['dir']." limit  $start, $limit";
$res1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
$recordsTotal =  mysqli_num_rows($res1);
$recordsFiltered =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
$asd = array();
$final_array = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res1) ) {
 $dataArray = array();
    $dataArray[] = $row["id"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["first_name"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["last_name"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["phone_no"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["mobile"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["city"];
    $dataArray[] = $row["zip"];
    $asd[]=$dataArray;
 }

$final_array = array("draw" => $draw, "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal, "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered, "data" => $asd, "sql" => $sql1);
echo json_encode($final_array); exit;
?>
```

Hope this example will help you for your concern.
please vote positive if this example will helpfull

Comment: Studying it now, I'll get back to you ASAP. Thank you.